# Error message when using strptime (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, strptime

I get an error message when using `strptime` trying to convert a string extracted from a website into a date format. I have to convert the extracted text data into a string which I have done but I get an error message saying:

```
exceptions.ValueError: time data 'Sat 18th Apr 2015' does not match format '%a %d %b'.
```

I've checked the documentation and I think I have the right parameters. I really want to save this information into a database in a `YYYY,MM,DD` format.

This is how i try to solve the problem

```
    item ['date'] = info.xpath('.//span[@class="dates"]//text()').extract() # Extract date information.
    convert = ''.join(str(t)for t in item['date'])+" 2015"
    print convert
    time.strptime(convert, "%a %dth %b %Y")
```

Inserting into a database like so...

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):    
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO info (venue, datez, dateForm, link, genre) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (item['artist'][0], item['date'][0], item['dateForm'][0], item['trackz'], "clubbing"))        
            self.conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

            return item
```

Comment: `%d` doesn't support ordinals, get rid of the `th` there.

Comment: where is the year coming from?

Comment: sorry, forgot to put the year on...

Comment: any tips on getting rid of the ordinal?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it ignore the 'Sat'?

Comment: @DanielParkinm why do you want to ignore Sat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `re` or `dateutil` just `rstrip` the letters after splitting:

```
from datetime import datetime

a, b, c = item["date"][0].split()

print(datetime.strptime("{} {} {} {}".format(a,b.rstrip("ndthstr"),c,"2015"),"%a %d %b %Y").strftime("%Y,%m,%d"))

2015,04,18
```

Comment: I've edited the question to show how i was obtaining the data... Might need a different approach? Thanks for your halp Padraic

Comment: @DanielParkin, try `''.join(t.rstrip("thrdstn") if t[0].isdigit() else t for t in item['date'])` That will strip the th,nd,st etc.. presuming each `t` is  separate string. Are the elements not already strings though?

Comment: Still get an error message. Which seems strange to me... 

'exceptions.ValueError: time data 'Sat 18th Apr 2015' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y'.'

Comment: Can you print item [date] and show me what it looks like?

Comment: item date is what is printed in the error message without the '2015'. To be exact  '[u'Sat 18th Apr']' is how it comes out in the terminal

Comment: ok that is the problem, it is a single string you don't need join, I will edit

Comment: Works really well mate. Thankyou so much. Can i annoy you slightly further though... Im trying to add these dates to a mysql database with the column type set to date. I get this error when running the script and the date stays at 0000-00-00        exceptions.TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: so you are supposed to pass datetime objects or strings?

Comment: datetime. I ideally want users to be able to search for a gig using a datepicker calendar. If this can be done with string variables i don't mind using them, but i imagine datetime objects would be better?

Comment: Ok, the problem is I have used strftime to create the format you want, if you want datetime objects and mysql can to the formatting just remove the strftime

Comment: so the code should look like this :   ' item['dateForm']=(datetime.strptime("{} {} {} {}".format(a,b.rstrip("ndthstr"),c,"2015"),"%a %d %b %Y")) ' It still gives me the same error... Sorry im a right pain. never used python besore so im kind of blagging this!! ;)

Comment: I am not overly familiar with mysql, how are you inserting?

Comment: scrap that... I've got rid of the error. Needed to alter the insert. However the date column information still remains 0000-00-00. the type is set to date if that might be the problem. If i get rid of the strftime i get another error

Comment: can you show me how you are inserting?

Comment: just edited the question mate

Comment: dateForm is the item used...

Comment: sorted. needed to remove the [0]. You my friend are an absolute diamond. I honestly really appreciate the help. If you live in London ill buy you a pint!! ;)

Comment: lol no worries, if I make it to london I will take you up on it ;)

Comment: Alright Padraic? me again... Ive run into a problem with your solution. When the date i scrape is one date "to" the next one, it breaks. Any thoughts? Hope your well?

Comment: Hi, good thanks, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: basically it works perfectly. Until my spider crawls something like "3rd Aug 2015 to 5th Aug 2015". Then it gets a list index out of range error.